# How do I build a probability matrix output layer in Keras

Tags: keras, deep-learning

Suppose I need to build a network that takes two inputs:

1. A patient's information, represented as an array of features
2. Selected treatment, represented as one-hot encoded array

Now how do I build a network that outputs a 2D probability matrix A where A[i,j] represents the probability the patient will end up at state j under treatment i. Let's say there are n possible states, and under any treatment, the total probability of all n states sums up to 1.

I wanted to do this because I was motivated by a similar network, where the inputs are the same as above, but the output is a 1d array representing the expected lifetime after treatment i is delivered. And such network is built as follows:

```
def default_dense(feature_shape, n_treatment):
    feature_input = keras.layers.Input(feature_shape)
    treatment_input = keras.layers.Input((n_treatments,))
    hidden_1 = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(feature_input)
    hidden_2 = keras.layers.Dense(16, activation = 'relu')(hidden_1)
    output = keras.layers.Dense(n_treatments)(hidden_2)
    output_on_action = keras.layers.multiply([output, treatment_input])
    model = keras.models.Model([feature_input, treatment_input], output_on_action)
    model.compile(optimizer=tf.optimizers.Adam(0.001),loss='mse')
    return model
```

And the training is simply

```
model.fit(x = [features, encoded_treatments], y = encoded_treatments * lifetime[:, np.newaxis], verbose = 0)
```

This is super handy because when predicting, I can use np.ones() as the encoded_treatments, and the network gives expected lifetimes under all treatments, thus choosing the best one is one-step. Certainly I can create multiple networks, each for a treatment, but it would be much less efficient.

Now the questions is, can I do the same to probability output?

Answer (score 0):

I have figured it out myself. The trick is to use RepeatVector() and Permute() layers to generate a matrix mask for treatments.

The output is an element-wise Multiply() of the mask and a Softmax() of same size.